# Best way to create a patch to community when I do a git rebase with conflicts

Tags: git, patch

I have a doubt related to creating patches and rebase them into master branch. For example:

I'm working in a separated branch from master and I generated 5 commits of change. So, I want to send this commits as a patch to community. To Linux Kernel for example.

New commits were added in master branch by other developers and when I rebase my 5 patches into master some conflicts appears.

Well, Do I need to generated a new patch that solve the conflicts? So, Do I need to send 5 + 1 patches (my 5 commits + 1 conflict resolve commit)?

I'd like to know what are the policies to send a patch and fix merging conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to resolve these conflicts --- without creating unnecessary "noise" in your patches, is to rebase your branch atop the new master, and then create your patch-series. This gives you the opportunity to fix any conflicts, without distracting the recipients with a "tacked-on-the-end-to-fix-all-the-conflicts" patch. (I believe this workflow is discussed (or at least mentioned) in the "getting started" documentation in the Linux kernel.)

Update the master branch

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

Rebase your changes onto the latest upstream HEAD (orig/master, master)

```
git checkout mybranch
git rebase master

# Resolve rebase conflicts here
```

Create your patch. At this point, the patch should apply *cleanly* to upstream HEAD, because of the rebase.

```
git format-patch master
```

NB: These commands untested, and from memory.

Answer (score 1):

That's not "a doubt", it's a question.

> I rebase my 5 patches into master some conflicts appears.

How did you resolve the conflicts?

You should have had to resolve them to finish the rebase, so there should still only be 5 commits in your branch, not 5+1.

If you do `git log master..` on your branch you should see the commits that you need to send. If you did the rebase correctly (and didn't commit conflicts or broken code) then there should still only be 5 commits to send.

Because the conflicts only ever existed in your branch, and you should have resolved them locally, noone else should ever know they existed, so you shouldn't need to send them any patches to resolve anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`git format-patch <since> | <revision range>`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html)

> Prepare each commit with its patch in one file per commit, formatted to resemble UNIX mailbox format. The output of this command is convenient for e-mail submission or for use with git am.
>
> There are two ways to specify which commits to operate on.
>
> ```
> 1. A single commit, <since>, specifies that the commits leading to the tip of the current branch that are not in the history that leads to the <since> to be output.
>
> 2. Generic <revision range> expression means the commits in the specified range.
> ```